# Rename function not working as expected

Tags: php

I'm using PHP to batch rename some local photos. The script is in the same directory as the photos.

The photos are named like `872376237_Photo_1_001.jpg`. The first set of numbers (before the first underscore) is different for each file, and that's what I want to remove.

The format for the new file name should be `Photo_1_001.jpg`. In the PHP I get the new file name by using `$newfilename = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '_') + 1);`. Echo'ing out `$newfilename` shows the correct new file name.

The problem is when I call `rename($filename, $newfilename)` the files are getting renamed to `1_001.jpg`. The `$newfilename` variable definitely contains the correct new file name. If I use `copy()` instead of `rename()` it works as expected. I can't figure this out.

Here's the code:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $filename = $fileinfo->getFilename();
        if ($filename != basename(__FILE__)) { // skip this script
            $newfilename = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '_') + 1);
            rename($filename, $newfilename);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: DevZer0 explained why this is happening in the comments. I thought DirectoryIterator compiled a list of all the files before iterating, but it does not. It will continuously iterate as long as new files are created (or renamed).

There's probably a better way to do this, but this works:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
$filenames = [];

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $filename = $fileinfo->getFilename();

        if ($filename != basename(__FILE__)) {
            $newfilename = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '_') + 1);
            array_push($filenames, [$filename, $newfilename]);
        }
    }
}

foreach ($filenames as $file) {
    rename($file[0], $file[1]);
}
```

Comment: your renaming the file continuously. make sure to add a negative clause so it won't rename once that starts with `Photo_`

Comment: I considered that, but if it was being renamed continuously wouldn't the file get renamed to `001.jpg`?

Comment: Also note that your script will rename any files regardless of whether they contain an underscore. A file called foo.txt will become oo.txt. And it will also rename any directories.

Comment: @Gordon, yeah I know that. This was just for a quick one-off rename job only, then I got stuck on this rename function behavior. I've already used `copy()` instead and got my files renamed, but I really want to know why `rename()` is behaving this way.

Comment: Put `echo "$filename -> $newfilename", PHP_EOL;` before the rename. Then run the script. That will explain what happens.

Comment: @Gavin I _guess_ when you rename during iterate, you would get _undefined behavior_: how it actually runs depends on how this API is implemented on your platform and maybe plus a couple of other environment factors.

Comment: DevZer0 passerby you should post this as an answer.

Comment: it is not good to operate and loop same list

Comment: Yeah it was continuously iterating. If DevZer0 can answer this I'll mark it as the answer.